# MacBook Pro - How to resume APFS decryption process?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-utility, encryption, apfs

I was decrypting a drive from Recovery menu and I restarted machine because it was taking a lot of time but now the decryption has been Paused at 42%.

I listed all available options using `diskutil apfs` and there isn't any option to resume/revert decryption process. I also tried to verify/repair disk option but it is still paused.

I found this command but it is for other file system.

`diskutil cs revert /Volumes/title_drive -passphrase`

As this file system is new so I was not able to find any helpful material on any site.

Please tell me, how can I resume the decryption process.

Answer (score 5):

The process is totally automatic in High Sierra and there is no command to resume the decryption process other than connecting the Mac to power if it's a portable Mac.

The Apples new file system `APFS` works differently then older file systems `HFS+`. The detailed guideline along with new feature detail can be [found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/FAQ/FAQ.html).

Now, whenever you'll **unlock volume** the pending/paused encryption/decryption process will **start automatically**. But there is a **condition**, the machine (in my case, MacBook Pro) must should be plugged in. So, whenever you'll unplug the decryption process will stop immediately even if the battery is fully charged since this is presumably a maintenance task that shouldn't deplete the battery energy at any time.